# How to use Concat in a where clause in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, where-clause

I am trying to collect all the names with an extension at the end of a string in MYSQL.

Table1

```
ID  | Name 
 0    Bob 1
 1    Bob 2
 2    Joe 1
 3    Joe 2
 4    Bob
 5    Joe
```

The query I'm running is similar to this one:

```
SELECT ID, name
FROM Fname
WHERE name = CONCAT(name,' ','1');`
```

Where I want to collect all the Names that end it a space and 1.

Answer (score 2):

Use `like`:

```
where name like '% 1'
```